# loading a subset of a file using Pig

Tags: csv, hadoop, nosql, apache-pig

I am playing with hortonworks sandbox to learn hadoop etc.

I am trying to load a file on a single machine "cluster":

```
A = LOAD 'googlebooks-eng-all-3gram-20090715-0.csv' using PigStorage('\t')
AS (ngram:chararray, year:int, count1:int, count2:int, count3:int);
B = LIMIT A 10;
Dump B;
```

Unfortunately the file is slightly too big for the ram that I have on my VM..

I am wondering if it's possible to `LOAD` a subset of the .`csv` file?

**Is something like this possible:**

```
LOAD 'googlebooks-eng-all-3gram-20090715-0.csv' using PigStorage('\t') LOAD ONLY FIRST 100MB?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why exactly do you need to load the entire file into RAM? You should be able to run the whole file regardless of how much memory you need. Try adding this to the top of your script:

```
--avoid java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space (execmode: -x local)
set io.sort.mb 10;
```

Your pig script will now read as:

```
--avoid java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space (execmode: -x local)
set io.sort.mb 10;
A = LOAD 'googlebooks-eng-all-3gram-20090715-0.csv' using PigStorage('\t')
AS (ngram:chararray, year:int, count1:int, count2:int, count3:int);
B = LIMIT A 10;
Dump B;
```

Assuming you're just getting an OutOfMemoryError when you are running your script, this should solve your problem.

Comment: thank you very much. i actually dont know how to check the logs yet. i'm completely new to this. i dont know what the problem was, but this works for me now!! can you please tell me what does set io.sort do?

Comment: It just changes the amount of memory used during the job's sort phase. Since the job will only use 10MB max, you can be sure that you won't run out of memory. In a real-world situation (using a real cluster), you obviously would not want to limit the amount of memory you can use.

Comment: No problem! I've been working with Hadoop/Pig recently, and about to get started working with MongoDB. I'm a researcher so the tools I use tend to vary over time. Not really stuck with one thing as of yet :)

Comment: cool! interested at all in working together ?  i come from a traditional RDBMS background with plenty of programming experience. im working on trying to setup a hortonworks cluster

Comment: I would love to, but unfortunately I'm working on several other projects simultaneously. I would prefer not to spread myself too thin. Maybe in the future, though!

Comment: understood! we all have that challenge of trying to stick to something and allowing it flourish,.

Answer (score 1):

The way you define you solutions is not possible while in Hadoop however if you can achieve your objective when you are in OS Shell, rather than Hadoop shell. In Linux shell you can write a script to read first 100MB from source file, save it to local file system and then use as Pig source.

```
#Script .sh
# Read file and save 100 MB content in file system
# Create N files of 100MB each
# write a pig_script to process your data as shown below
# Launch Pig script and pass the N files as parameter as below: 
pig -f pigscript.pig -param inputparm=/user/currentuser/File1.File2,..,FileN

#pigscript.pig 
A = LOAD '$inputparm' using PigStorage('\t') AS (ngram:chararray, year:int, count1:int, count2:int, count3:int); 
B = LIMIT A 10; 
Dump B;
```

In general case, multiple files can be passed in Hadoop shell by their name, so you call out file names from Hadoop shell as well.

The key here is that in Pig there is no default way to read x from a file and process, it is all or nothing so you may need to find ways to solve achieve your objective.